# class or function utility in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How and when do you create a utility/helper class or function in angular2?

I have created a folder called `helpers` for all the general functions and classes that will be created.

but now I have this code that will be used on 8 components.

```
/**
   * this is initialize after the elements have been loaded. called inside ngAfterViewInit methods
   * this sets up the joyrideService
   */
  joyRideInit(): void {
    const fileNameNotes = this.designNotes.map((matchImgUrl) =>
      extractKeyFromFilename(matchImgUrl)
    );

    const seenNotes = {
      viewed_notes: {
        match: fileNameNotes,
        ...this.viewedNotes
      }
    };

    this.joyrideService
      .startTour({
        steps: [
          'matchFirst',
          ...this.designNotes,
          'guidedTourBtn',
          'saveNextBtn'
        ]
      })
      .subscribe(null, null, () => {
        this.updateUserNotes(seenNotes);
      });
  }

  /**
   * sends a resquest to update the notes
   * @param userUpdateNotes 
   */
  updateUserNotes(userUpdateNotes): void {
    this.userService
      .updateUser(userUpdateNotes, this.user.id)
      .pipe(
        first(),
        map((result) => {
          // * result no used.
          console.log('res', result);
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          console.error('display-notes#nextNoteOrClose: error in ', error);
          throw error;
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

should I make this as a class or functions? this will have 4 arguments coming from the components that will be using this.

Answer (score 0):

create Shared/Common service, and all the methods like this you could put it there to have an injection by default.

Comment: thank you buy im confused how to use it. do I need to inject or put the class inside the constructor? if I invoke new it will ask for arguments.